# PSNUP, Converting 1st Page only

Tags: postscript

I am trying to use PSNUP to Shrnk my PS file but it is effective on 1st page only, and not working on o

Anybody who knows may help please.

MY sample File can be downloaed from :-

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e2le3rvlx9w1yw/1010467351.ps?m

Answer (score 1):

your file is not DSC (Document Structuring Convention) compliant, and so utilities that rely on special comments are not going to work.  Sorry this doesnt really help solve the problem but at least understand it..

---

verified luser droogs sugestion works. Presuming you want the first page to remain full size this is what you need to do:

```
ps2ps file.ps - | psselect -p1 > out.ps
ps2ps file.ps - | psselect -p2- | psnup -4 >> out.ps
```

Comment: It might be possible to pass it through `ps2ps` to add the necessary DSC comments.